# Missing roads of San Francisco and extra parts on the map

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

I'm using OSM dataset of San Francisco that I have imported using osm2po to PostgreSQL and I think that there are some data missing, because when I use pgr-astar to find the shortest path, there is sometimes no result, so there are some roads between some points that are not available on my dataset.
In other words there are some segments of roads unavailble on my dataset.
[image]

Additionally, when I compare the map of San Francisco generated by this dataset with the one generated with the osm file without any convertion or manipulation, it's visible that there are some roads missing.
Does osm2po had eliminate some roads? how to avoid this problem please

The map of San Francisco(osm2po dataset)

[image]

The map of San Francisco(osm dataset)

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps have a look at some manually that are missing and see what tags they have -- perhaps they are marked as tracks or footpaths?

Comment: Thank you for answering I will check the content of the default file of osm2po.